# Laravel 7: Find days and dates between two dates with condition

Tags: php, laravel, conditional-formatting

When the user submits a leave application, needs to select the start and end date.  But before saving it needs to check is there any holiday or weekly holiday in between two dates. If a holiday or weekly holiday matches then the total number of holidays will be deducted from the total days.

Weekly Holiday:

| id | day | working_status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fri | 1 |

Holiday Table: (Model Name: Holiday)

| id | date | publication_status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-26 | 1 |

Leave Table:

| id | start_date | end_date | total_days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-25 | 2022-05-28 | 2 |

Controller:

```
$leave = new User;
  $leave->start_date = $request->start_date;
  $leave->end_date = $request->end_date;
  
  //get and convert day name for weekly holiday compare like Fri, Sat etc.
  $start_day = date("D", strtotime($request->start_date));
  $end_day = date("D", strtotime($request->end_date));

  // get and convert date for monthly holiday compare
  $start = strtotime($request->start_date);
  $end = strtotime($request->end_date);
  
  $diff = $end - $start;
  $diff_in_days = floor($diff/(60*60*24)) + 1;
  // Suppose  Fri is holiday now we have to count how many Fri day in between start and end date. 
  here need help
   $weekly_holidays = WorkingDay::where('working_status', 1)
         ->get(['day'])->count();

    // we have to count how many Monthly holiday in between start and end date. here need help
   $monthly_holidays= Holiday::where('publication_status', 1)->get(['date'])->count();
    
   $total_days = $diff_in_days - ($weekly_holidays + $monthly_holidays);
       if($request->halfday == 1){
                $leave->total_days = 0.5;
            }
            else{
                $leave->total_days = $total_days;
            }
```

Example:

```
 WorkingDay = day = Fri
 Holiday = date = 2022-05-26
 start_date = 2022-05-25
 end_date = 2022-05-28
 total_days = 2 
 // from 25 to 28, the total days are 4, but 26 is a holiday, and 27 is Friday. Holidays can be multiple dates. If there is multiple holidays between the start and end date, it will calculate according to this.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually easier. You don't need to complicate it. `Carbon` comes to the rescue here.

```
$startDate = Carbon::parse('start date here');
$endDate = Carbon::parse('date string here');

$weekdays = $startDate->diffInWeekdays($endDate);
```

This will give you the day difference in weekdays excluding any weekends.

Now whichever database you use, you would have a function to get the day of the week in number where `0 stands for Sunday` and `6 for Saturday`.
For Postgres, I will give you an example

```
weekdays_holiday_count = select count(*) from holidays where date_part('dow', date) not in (0, 6) # 0 for Sunday and 6 for Saturday
```

This query is counting holidays which came on weekdays. I give you the raw query here. however, the point here is to under the magic of the function.

Now you can do the math easily

```
$weekdays - $weekdays_holiday_count
```

Make sure to import `Carbon\Carbon` at the top.

Comment: But my weekend comes from the database. For this, if I fetch the weekend from the database and put this ($days) instead of (0,6), will that work?

Comment: Sure. You can. @ShanMdShazarulHaque171-15-